# Error converting Tensorflow to coreML using tf-coreml

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml

I want to do hand tracking with coreML.

For this, I took the ready-made tensorFlow model: https://github.com/timctho/convolutional-pose-machines-tensorflow

And I'm trying to convert it to coreML using tf-coreml. But during the conversion I get errors.

```
(base) MBP-Alexey:Desktop alexeygorbunov$ python convert_tf_to_coreml.py

Loading the TF graph...
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "convert_tf_to_coreml.py", line 5, in <module>
    input_name_shape_dict  = { ' input_placeholder: 0 ' : [ 1 , 256 , 256 , 3 ]})   
File "/Users/alexeygorbunov/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 586, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)   
File "/Users/alexeygorbunov/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tfcoreml/_tf_coreml_converter.py", line 150, in _convert_pb_to_mlmodel
 gdef.ParseFromString(serialized)  
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

What could be the error and how to solve it?

Comment: Try it with Python 3.5 instead of 3.7.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I realized that the tf model does not suit me, as it weighs too much. I want to make a recognition of 20 points on the hand using turicreate, because it can be converted to squeezene. Can this be done with turicreate or not? I am studying the documentation, but I cannot find a similar example, could you tell me what kind of model classification it is?
Is it suitable for me (http://cocodataset.org/#download) or is it better?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Turi Create only lets you train a few different types of models and this is not one of them. What you're attempting to do is very similar to "pose estimation", but instead of detecting different body parts you detect different parts of the hand.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Are there any other options besides how to write your own on squeezenet? Is it possible to convert ready-made models to squeezenet?

Comment: Yes you can convert existing models to SqueezeNet. This is often known as "knowledge distillation" where you train a student model (SqueezeNet in your case) to learn the knowledge from a teacher model. But AFAIK there are no easy-to-use tools for this, and so you'll have to write your own code.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Hi, I have a new question. I created the CoreML model using Microsoft CustomVision for object tracking, and the output is "model_outputs0: MultiArray (Double)". I can not understand how to "MultiArray (Double)" convert, are there coreM ready functions?

Comment: You will have to write your own code to convert that MLMultiArray into actual bounding boxes. Here is an example: http://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph -- but you will probably have to change the logic depending on whatever architecture Microsoft's thing is trained with (I don't recall if it is YOLO or SSD).